# POST data doesn't get sent to a PHP script

Tags: php, android

My app tries to send POST data like this:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/mydir/");

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender_app", "My app"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("someString", "My string"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

And the script logs this request for testing purposes like this:

```
ob_start();
var_dump($_REQUEST);
$request_dump = "_REQUEST: ".ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents("requests.log",$request_dump, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

The app makes the request successfully and it gets logged, but the `$_REQUEST` superglobal is always empty and `sender_app` and `someString` post variables are not being set.

The `$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]` is reported as `Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)` so at least that's being sent.

The log looks like this:

```
_REQUEST: array(0) {
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: I don't understand how `$_REQUEST` is always empty but "it gets logged", when the string you're logging is the result of `var_dump($_REQUEST);`. Can you paste an example from the log?

Comment: I've updated the question to show how the log looks like after the request. The request gets received but no variables are set.

Comment: My only suggestion at this point is to check the $_POST superglobal.

Comment: I tried that, it's also empty.

Comment: What gives your $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ?

Comment: _SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] is "GET". Now why would that be?

Comment: Then maybe this can help a little : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553718/request-array-is-empty-all-of-a-sudden

Comment: Thanks, that's it! The problem was that (despite what I wrote in the code snipped in the question, which I did for clarity) my URL was `http://localhost/mydir/` which was redirected to the `index.php` in that directory, turning it into a GET request as explained in the question you linked. Anyway, now the URL points to the actual script rather than relying on the server to redirect to the default document and it works!